# Store a row value from a .csv using python

Tags: linux, csv

This is the first time I try the linux programming...
I have a csv file made like this

> nothing; V;V;V;F;V;F;V;V;
> nothing; V;V;V;F;V;F;V;V;

the columns are fixed but the rows can be increased in future.
I want to read the value of each row and save it into a variable, which I need to investigate for future operations.
Right now the problem is how to open and store into a variable the value of each cell of the csv.
I've tried with the command

```
Folder_path=file.csv
For /f "skip=1" in ($Folder_path)
```

but it gives me an error.
Furthermore I think a while loop should be better than the for but honestly I'ven't understood how to construct it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: as I've written I have a CSV done as you can read before, and from that I want to have in a variable the value "V" the value  "F" the value "nothing". how can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
c=1
while read row
do
    echo "row $c:  $row"
    IFS='; ' read -r -a cols_arr <<< "$row"
    #declare -p cols_arr
    for((i=0; i<${#cols_arr[@]}; i++))
    do
        echo "row $c: --- column $(($i+1)): variable is \${cols_arr[$i]} has value ${cols_arr[$i]}"
    done
    c=$((c+1))
done < csvfile


row 1:  nothing; V;V;V;F;V;F;V;V; nothing; V;V;V;F;V;F;V;V;
row 1: --- column 1: variable is ${cols_arr[0]} has value nothing
row 1: --- column 2: variable is ${cols_arr[1]} has value V
row 1: --- column 3: variable is ${cols_arr[2]} has value V
row 1: --- column 4: variable is ${cols_arr[3]} has value V
row 1: --- column 5: variable is ${cols_arr[4]} has value F
row 1: --- column 6: variable is ${cols_arr[5]} has value V
row 1: --- column 7: variable is ${cols_arr[6]} has value F
row 1: --- column 8: variable is ${cols_arr[7]} has value V
row 1: --- column 9: variable is ${cols_arr[8]} has value V
row 1: --- column 10: variable is ${cols_arr[9]} has value nothing
row 1: --- column 11: variable is ${cols_arr[10]} has value V
row 1: --- column 12: variable is ${cols_arr[11]} has value V
row 1: --- column 13: variable is ${cols_arr[12]} has value V
row 1: --- column 14: variable is ${cols_arr[13]} has value F
row 1: --- column 15: variable is ${cols_arr[14]} has value V
row 1: --- column 16: variable is ${cols_arr[15]} has value F
row 1: --- column 17: variable is ${cols_arr[16]} has value V
row 1: --- column 18: variable is ${cols_arr[17]} has value V
```